# Trouble finding the right headset for a tapered fork 1.1/8 to 1.25 for a semi integrated compatible 44 mm headtube

Tags: headset

I'm building a bike for which I bought a 2015 Cube Aerium HPA Pro frame. I also have a Focus Evo 6th element fork. The fork is tapered from 1.1/8 to 1.25 inch, my headtube is 44 mm inner diameter. The headtube takes a semi-integrated headset. When looking for a headset I am not able to find ZS44/28.6 upper, ZS44/33.0 lower stack. I can only find integrated headsets with these meausrements.
My question is whether someone knows where you can get a semi integrated stack with these measurements in Europe, or if it is not possible if there is a solution that I can use, like thickening the fork with a aluminium ring or something.

Furthermore, is there a way to let integrated headsets fit in a frame that is meant for semi-integrated headsets.
many thanks in advance

Comment: there is not much space for ZS headset for a tapered fork within an 44 mm headset. maybe you could  fit an EC headset? might look a bit stupid

Comment: Do you know whether there is an adapter for EC44/40 to 33 cm, because EC44/40 is readily available but EC40/33 is not. Can i make my 1.25 inch fork fit in the EC44/40 bottom headset? Surely this exists somewhere.

Comment: EC44/33 is not available? Cane creek and Ritchey make them, and I think even Chris King if you want to get fancy. There are adapters or adapter crown races, it might be easier to find the when you search for 1 1/2" and 1 1/4" instead of millimeters. Found one at cnc-bike.de.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using a ZS44 lower here, you're using EC44. Thus there is no solution that doesn't jack up the head tube angle away from what's intended, unless the fork had an unusually low axle to crown dimension.

The solutions available depend on whether the fork has an integral crown race, as opposed to taking a pressed crown race (like what would come with a headset). Integral is pretty common on all-carbon road forks. If you didn't have integral, you need any EC44/33 lower and any ZS44/28.6 upper. The King Inset 8 is a complete headset that matches that, and Cane Creek and FSA both have options you would assemble out of separately purchased uppers and lowers.

If it's an integral crown race, you must determine whether the nominally EC44/33 lower you're looking at is actually the same cup and bearing as would come with an EC44/40 plus a reducer race, since you wouldn't be able to do this via a reducer. That piece of information is typically hidden outside the printed specs on this type of headset and you'll probably need to contact the manufacturer to know. I believe the King Inset 8 is like that and probably some others are too.